# How to group two nodes which are not related in xpath?

Tags: xpath

I have html structure like this:

```html
<a>
  <c>
  </c>
</a>
<b>
  <d>
  </d>
</b>

<a>
  <c>
  </c>
</a>
<b>
  <d>
  </d>
</b>
```

How do I group node 'a' and node 'b' together?
The xpath should be able to select the pairs of node 'a' and 'b'.
The nodes have auto generated id's and name's so I can't use them in xpath.

Comment: Please explain what the output should look like and what programming language you are using. Also, your input is not a well-formed document.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `|` operator for two unrelated XPath Expressions:

```
 (//a | //b)
```